# Is it possible to get smart window placement?

Tags: window-manager

For those who are not familiar with this, smart placement was an option in Compiz that arranged windows avoiding to overlap them. For example, if you open a file manager, then a text editor, and finally a terminal window, you get something like this:

[image]

Is it possible to get this in Loki?

Comment: Quick tip for your icons. Change Inherits=Numix to Inherits=elementary in /usr/share/icons/Numix-Circle/index.theme and your wingpanel icons will be more evenly sized and spaced.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelRoberts, but the panel icons issue is solved [symlinking some icons](https://github.com/numixproject/numix-icon-theme/issues/1154), inherits doesn't help, however, it was very useful in swichboard!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no.

Long answer:

It is not an option in gala, elementary OS' default window manager. You can install other window mangers and replace gala with something like compiz by editing
`/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/pantheon.session`

Gala is pretty central to elementary OS. If you try using another window manager you are likely to experience issues. I installed compiz on my laptop just to see what would happen. It sort of works. There is no desktop background and wingpanel segfaults. Plank loads but doesn't hide properly. Perhaps with enough tweaking it could be made usable.

Comment: The lack of background can be solved changing the file manager... but to suggest it as an enhance would be better than touch critical system components.